# Neo4j admin load dump file gives "system cannot find the path specified" no matter the path

Tags: neo4j

I created a Neo4j graph on one computer, and I want to transfer it to another computer. The recommended way to do this according to the (sparse) documentation is to  `dump`  the file, then  `load` it using the admin tools via the terminal.

So I did that once successfully to transfer the existing graph to another computer to run the algorithm to add new nodes (it took two weeks), and now I want to transfer it back to my main computer and I can't get it to work.

Specifically, no matter where I put the file, and no matter what path I specify (obviously the path always points to the actual location) it always gives me the error

`The system cannot find the path specified.`

I even put my dump file in a directory in a similar relative location as the example in the documentation (rather than a convenient location and absolute path) and I still got this error.  That is, the documentation says:

`bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/backups/graph.db/2016-10-02.dump --database=graph.db --force`

and my command is:

`bin/neo4j-admin load --from=/backups/backup_graph_20181225.dump --database=graph.db --force`

and it can't find the path.

So it occurs to me that perhaps the error message does not accurately describe the problem. Perhaps there is a different config problem, such as permissions or ... I really don't know. As I said, I didn't have this problem going in the other direction.

Does anybody have any idea why could be causing this error and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, it was just a small error.  I needed to remove the leading slash from my backup directory.

```
bin/neo4j-admin load --from=backups/backup_graph_20181225.dump --database=graph.db --force
```